# Checking the existence of a Postgres database from Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I found myself needing to check the existence of a Postgres database from Ruby, and ended up with the following (ugly) code:

```
def database_exists        
  `sudo su postgres -c 'psql -l | grep #{database_name} | wc -l'`.strip.to_i > 0
end
```

My concern is that not only is this not water-tight, but there must be a function already out there to do this sort of thing.

Can anyone let me know what functions exist in Ruby to do this cleanly ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not as efficient as your code and requires the use of the `pg` library (https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg):

```
require 'pg'

def database_exists?(database_name)
  conn = PG.connect(:dbname => 'postgres')
  res = conn.exec("SELECT datname FROM pg_database").values.flatten
  res.include?(database_name)
end
```

You could probably make this more efficient by adding `where datname = #{database_name}` to the query and checking for an empty result set.